# function of infinitive clause

Tags: infinitive-clauses

From BBC news,

> The Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC) accused Mr Musk of breaching a court order **to not share information which could impact the financial markets**, without pre-approval.

Is the **to** here the equivalent of **in order to**?

Or does the entire infinitive phrase adds information to **order** , telling us what kind of order was breached.

Comment: Your second thought is on track. The infinitival is a complement, licensed by the NP "court order".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC) accused Mr Musk of*
>   *breaching* [*a court order to not share information which could impact*
>   *the financial markets, without pre-approval*].

No: it's not an purpose adjunct, but a complement licensed by "court order".

Purpose adjuncts express cause, but there is no causal meaning here.  The complement simply expands the meaning of "court order".

Comment: It has nothing to do with syntax , readers have to figure out whether the infinitive clause in this sentence is complement based on the context, is my understanding right?

Comment: @jammyyang The grammar and meanings work together. Compare these three examples: "We booked early _so that we could be sure of getting good seats_" (purpose adjunct) /  "We couldn't get on the plane _because the airline had overbooked_" (result adjunct) /  "The airline had overbooked, _so that we couldn't get on the plane_" (result adjunct).

Comment: Thank you, what if I complicate the sentence a little bit, "We support the decision he made to fire the incompetent workers" . The infinitive clause will be complement a complement licensed by gap(expanding the meaning of gap), and gap derives the meaning from decision, is this right?

Comment: Yes: "We support the decision (that) he made ____   to fire the incompetent workers". Here the infinitival is complement of 'gap', which is interpreted as "decision".